# Wait until the user object is received

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am looking for a way to wait until the user object is received, before proceeding with the logic in the app.

```
saveFacebookCredentialsToFirebase(){

    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then( (data) => {
      let accessToken = data.accessToken
      let facebookCredential = Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken)

      Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).catch(function (error) {
          let errorCode = error.code
          let errorMessage = error.message
          let email = error.email
          let credential = error.credential
      })
    })
  }
```

How can I wait until `Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)` returns a valid user object with `user.uid` (and not just the promise), before proceeding with the logic in the app?

Comment: can't you do ...signInWithCredential(..).then ?

Comment: Yes, I ended up with that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
Firebase.auth()
.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
.then(response => {
 /* your logic here */
})
.catch(error => handleError())
```